# Create a new column by contatenating values within a group in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello everyone I have a dataframe such as :

```
  Groups Species Events
1      1     A_1      1
2      1     B_1      1
3      1     A_2      2
4      2     C_1      1
5      2     D_1      3
6      2     C_2      1
7      2     E_1      1
```

and I would like to add a new columns : `Newcol` where I add into a `[ ]` all the `df$Species` in the same `df$Groups` and `df$Events`   and separated by a coma. Here in the exemple I should get :

```
           Groups Species Events Newcol
    1      1     A_1      1      [A_1,B_1]
    2      1     B_1      1      [A_1,B_1]
    3      1     A_2      2      [C_2]
    4      2     C_1      1      [C_1,C_2,E_1]
    5      2     D_1      3      [D_1]
    6      2     C_2      1      [C_1,C_2,E_1]
    7      2     E_1      1      [C_1,C_2,E_1]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `groupby` with `transform`

```
df['out'] = df.groupby(['Groups','Events'])['Species'].transform(lambda x : [x.tolist()]*len(x))
Out[276]: 
1         [A_1, B_1]
2         [A_1, B_1]
3              [A_2]
4    [C_1, C_2, E_1]
5              [D_1]
6    [C_1, C_2, E_1]
7    [C_1, C_2, E_1]
Name: Species, dtype: object
```

If just need str change to

```
df.groupby(['Groups','Events'])['Species'].transform(lambda x : '['+','.join(x)+']')
```

Comment: The `*len(x)` is tricky with `transform`. Does one really need it though? Or does Pandas do the broadcasting?

Comment: @QuangHoang without that I think transform will not output M-D array ~

Answer (score 1):

Following should work using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
res = df.groupby(['Groups','Events']).apply(lambda group: group['Species'].values).reset_index()
pd.merge(df,res,on=['Groups','Events'],how='left')
```

Output:

```
Groups  Species Events  0
0   1   A_1 1   [A_1, B_1]
1   1   B_1 1   [A_1, B_1]
2   1   A_2 2   [A_2]
3   2   C_1 1   [C_1, C_2, E_1]
4   2   D_1 3   [D_1]
5   2   C_2 1   [C_1, C_2, E_1]
6   2   E_1 1   [C_1, C_2, E_1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `set_index()` and `.agg()`

```
l = ['Groups','Events']
df = df.set_index(l)
df['Newcol'] = df.groupby(l)['Species'].agg(list)
df.reset_index()
```